# Docker user defined network gateway timeout

Tags: nginx, docker, timeout, docker-network

We have 3 docker containers for our product in an ubuntu image.
In the first container, there is a tomcat application that provides a webservice using SOAP protocol. 
For this container, we have created a network to communicate with other containers with a static IP from other containers with below command:

```
docker network create --driver=bridge --subnet=172.18.0.0/16 apinet
```

After this we have created our api with below command:

```
docker run --net apinet --ip 172.18.0.10 -d -p 8080:8080 api
```

In the api, a service is returning huge data and we are getting 504 gateway timeout error after 45 seconds.

We have tried to use the api without specifying user defined network and we received the response data succesfully.

However, we need this user defined network to give a static IP to the api.

Is there anyway to extend the gateway timeout value for a user defined network?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your SOAP webservice require access to something on the internet?

Comment: ..or anything on an external network for that matter.

Comment: Exactly. It calls another web service from an external network.

Comment: There shouldn't be much of a difference in performance between the two so just check you have connectivity. Can you ping the external web service IP from the container?  If not do you have a `MASQUERADE` rule in the hosts iptables for the custom network? `iptables -t nat -vnL | grep 172.18`  If that returns a line it should have the correct bridge labeled with the custom networks id `!br-NETID`

Comment: We have found the solution. You're right its about `MASQUERADE` rule. When creating the user defined network,  `MASQUERADE` flag must be set to true. Ex: `docker network create --subnet=172.18.0.0/16 -o "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc=true"  -o "com.docker.network.driver.mtu=1500" -o "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade=true" -o "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4=172.18.0.1" cloudapinet`